# Integrate options product button with paypal price with PHP foreach

Tags: php, paypal

I am working on an imaginary store with PHP.
I have a file called manuals.json where I have my items:

```json
    {
    "cummins":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "Cummins",
            "categoria": "Trucks",
                "manuales":
                [
                    {
                        "id": "cumm1",
                        "nombre": "Starter Manual",
                        "precio": 80
                    },

                    {
                        "id": "cumm2",
                        "nombre": "Professional Manual",
                        "precio": 150
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "cumm3",
                        "nombre": "Service Manual",
                        "precio": 230
                    }
                ]
        }
    ],

    "mack":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "Mack",
            "categoria": "Trucks",
                "manuales":
                [
                    {
                        "id": "mack1",
                        "nombre": "Starter Manual",
                        "precio": 50
                    },

                    {
                        "id": "mack2",
                        "nombre": "Professional Manual",
                        "precio": 110
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "mack3",
                        "nombre": "Service Manual",
                        "precio": 200
                    }
                ]
        }
    ]}
```

I use that in my index.php:

```php
    <?php
    $brands_json = file_get_contents('manuals.json');
    $decoded_json = json_decode($brands_json, true);
    $brands = $decoded_json['cummins'];
```

And I want to show my products in a paypal dropdown. I'm trying to do it like this:

```php
    echo '
    <!-- OPTION LIST -->
    <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myPayPaleMail@gmail.com">
                            
    <!-- Specify an Add to Cart button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
                            
    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$nombre.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                            
    <!-- Provide a drop-down menu option field with prices. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Size">

    <select name="os1" id="os1">
    <option
    value="Select a size">Choose an Option...</option>
    ';
    // FOREACH
    foreach($brands as $brand) {
    $nombre = $brand['nombre'];
    $manuales = $brand['manuales'];
    $manualPrice = $brand['manuales'];
    foreach($manuales as $manual){
    echo '
    <option name="'.$manual['id'].'" value="'.$manual['id'].'">'.$manual['nombre']. " - $" .$manual['precio'].' USD</option>
    <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="1">
    ';
    ?>
    </select>
    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" alt="Add to Cart">
    <img alt="" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
    </form>
```

Paypal reference: https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html-example-cart/#link-productoptionswithprices

But my result is:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

If I remove the "input" that PayPal needs to determine the price of the item, my options are displayed without any problem, however it works because I do not determine the price of the item.
Is there a way to determine the prices with those inputs without interfering with my "options"?

Comment: Where is your PHP opener tag of `<?` or similar? It looks like everything in your sample is being parsed as HTML

Comment: @PrestonPHX I just added the opening php tag.

Comment: That's not the code block that needs it, it's the following one where you are switching out of php to HTML. And a further problem seems to be that you are meaning to echo an HTML string, above the foreach, but you don't include this. Your code sample isn't valid.

Comment: @PrestonPHX I print some code before the foreach because I don't need it to be repeated, how should I do it so I don't have (for example) 10 times the "form" tag being opened?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to problems with your sample that seem to prevent it from displaying the options you want, your options are non-functional for pricing purposes since you do not include the pricing hidden inputs, which are separate from (but contextually linked with) the option selection. How to do so is shown in the document you referenced.

```
    <!-- Specify the price that PayPal uses for each option. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="2x4">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="3.95">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="3x5">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="4.95">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="4x6">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="5.95">
```

---

HTML cart upload is extremely old and clunkly, instead of learning how to work with such legacy HTML code you are better off using a current [PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), which uses JS.

For such an integration, choosing options will be done outside/above the button code (most simply with an HTML select). Based on this selection, your JS createOrder function must set the correct price (and also the line item information if desired). You can use `document.getElementById('....').value` or similar to get the price of the chosen option, likely using some kind of stock item array lookup to match a selection with its price.